# Hacer aparecer el reCaptcha a partir despues del 3º intento

Tags: php

El código siguiente muestra un recaptcha a los 3 intentos de login.

Realiza todas las consultas, inserta y elimina datos de la tabla. Lo que deseo es utilizar bien la variable del formulario del recaptcha por que me deja pasar si no presiono el recaptcha.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
  include_once "conexion/clsConexion.php";
  require_once "recaptchalib.php";
  $obj = new clsConexion;
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $consulta_ip = $obj->consultar("SELECT count(direccion_ip) AS login_intentos_fallidos FROM intentos_fallidos WHERE direccion_ip = '$ip' AND fecha_login_fallido BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()");
  foreach ((array) $consulta_ip as $row) {
    $intentos_fallidos = $row['login_intentos_fallidos'];
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>SANTA MARIA REYNA | Login</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body background="fondo.jpg">
<div class="login-box" id="todo-transparente">
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="login-box-body">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <img src="configuracion/foto/<?php echo $logo ?>" width="150" height="150" />
        </div>
        <p class="login-box-msg">Por favor ingrese su codigo y clave.</p>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" id="username" required placeholder="codigo" autocomplete="off" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="clave" id="password" required placeholder="clave" autocomplete="off" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <?php if (isset($intentos_fallidos) && $intentos_fallidos >= 3) {?>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfKazQUAAAAABb5TdsXhiXtPoKiVfZrwkaPjnC_" data-theme="dark"></div>
            <?php }?>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <button type="submit" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"> <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> Entrar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div align="center">
            <br />
            <span>2017</span> - <span>All rights reserved.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box-body -->
    <!-- /.login-box -->
    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
    <script src="plugins/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        //Asignas la clave secreta a una variable llamada $claveSecreta
        $claveSecreta = "6LfKazQUAAAAAJFGcTeZ4HfwKuRwvXTY3ZF_A3aR";
        // Por default asumimos que tenemos una respuesta vacía
        $respuesta = null;
        //Creamos una instancia de la clase que incluimos
        $captcha = new ReCaptcha($claveSecreta);
        //Validamos que si hayamos recibido por post la respuesta que recibimos de google al validar el captcha
        if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
            //Le pedimos a google que valide la respuesta del captcha para ello enviamos nuestro dominio y la respuesta
            $respuesta = $captcha->verifyResponse
            (
                $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
            );
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['codigo']) and !empty($_POST['clave'])) {
        $codigo = trim($obj->real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['codigo'], ENT_QUOTES))));
        $clave = trim($obj->real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['clave'], ENT_QUOTES))));
        $clavemd5 = md5($clave);
        $resultapo = $obj->consultar("select * from usuario where codigo='" . $obj->real_escape_string($codigo) . "' and clave='" . $obj->real_escape_string($clavemd5) . "'");
        foreach ((array) $resultapo as $row) {
        $valor = $row['codigo'];
        $estado = $row["estado"];
        $tipo = $row["tipo"];
        $obj->ejecutar("DELETE FROM intentos_fallidos WHERE direccion_ip = '$ip'");
    }
    //si el codigo no existe en la bd manda el mensaje de error es como decir $row['codigo']=nulo
    if (isset($valor) == '') {
        echo "<script>
        alertify.alert('Mensaje','Usuario y/o clave Incorrecta.', function(){
            alertify.message('OK');
            self.location='index.php';
        });
        </script>";
        if ($intentos_fallidos < 3) {
            $obj->ejecutar("INSERT INTO intentos_fallidos (direccion_ip,fecha_login_fallido) VALUES ('$ip', NOW())");
        }
        } else if ($estado != 'ACTIVO') {
            echo "<script>
            alertify.alert('Mensaje','Usted no se encuentra Activo en la base de datos.', function(){
                alertify.message('OK');
                self.location='index.php';
            });
            </script>";
        } else if ($tipo == 'ADMIN') {
            // esta sesion de autentificado lo pongo 1 para seguridad i despues haga la comprobacion si no es igual a 1 se redireccion al inicio
            $_SESSION["autentificado"] = 1;
            $_SESSION["codigo"] = $codigo;
            $_SESSION["clave"] = $clavemd5;
            header('location:inicio/index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

veo muy innecesario tener que guardar los intentos fallidos en una tabla, lo que podes hacer es almacenar los intentos en una variable de sesion, un contador y cuando llegue a 3 que te aparezca el captcha, no guardarlo en una tabla. Una vez que logre ingresar correctamente entonces eliminas la variable de session.

Saludos